# How to create a page template that display posts with a certain category in the Genesis Framework?

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

I know how to to create this kind of templates. Usually, I just start a custom WordPress loop. But when I checked a template file in the Genesis Framework I saw this:

**page_blog.php:**

```
<?php

/*

 WARNING: This file is part of the core Genesis framework. DO NOT edit

 this file under any circumstances. Please do all modifications

 in the form of a child theme.

 */



/**

 * Template Name: Blog

 * This file handles blog post listings within a page.

 *

 * This file is a core Genesis file and should not be edited.

 *

 * @category Genesis

 * @package  Templates

 * @author   StudioPress

 * @license  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GPL v2.0 (or later)

 * @link     http://www.studiopress.com/themes/genesis

 */

genesis();
```

This is the Blog Page and I'm puzzled.

How do I create a template that lists posts with a certain category?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've found a solution yet but this has always worked for me:

1. Do not edit the file you've copied the code for
2. Create a new page (or use an existing one) and set it's template to Blog
3. At the bottom of the same page under Custom Fields, type in query_args and then under value, type `cat=CATERGORY`
4. Hit publish and you should be good.